# WP8 updating app with a different Product ID

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I have an app in the app store and I would like to update the application. Can I upload a new XAP file with a different Product ID? Does it not affect the update process?

Also while uploading the application, is APP VERSION the only parameter to consider or are there any other parameters to consider?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as per the guidelines(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg442301(v=vs.105).aspx) we have to look into these parameters...
1. APP VERSION
2. PRODUCT ID (Which will be APP ID, you can find this in your developer page)